# How can I use datomic's pull method to grab an entity by its entity id?

Tags: clojure, datomic, datalog

How can I retrieve an entity using the `pull` method by its entity id? I've used transact to add some datoms/facts (right phrasing?) to my db. I can see the entity id's if I do a simple query like:

```
[:find ?e
 :where
 [?e :arb/value]
]
```

The result being:

> ## {[17592186045418] [17592186045420] [17592186045423]}

Now I'd like to retrieve one of these using [pull](http://docs.datomic.com/pull.html). The examples in the docs for pull, however, use examples where the entity in question is associated with an id.

Specifically, the docs refer to an example from the musicbrainz sample data set, and the sample they suggest is:

`(pull db '[*] led-zeppelin)`

where (although the docs don't show this) led-zeppelin has been defined like so (as can be seen [here](https://github.com/Datomic/day-of-datomic/blob/master/tutorial/pull.clj#L20):

`(def led-zeppelin [:artist/gid #uuid "678d88b2-87b0-403b-b63d-5da7465aecc3"])`

The docs say that the pull command takes three things: a db, a selector pattern determining I think what attributes are pulled for each entity, and the "eid" of the entity. So the above `led-zeppelin` var is somehow the eid.

I don't really follow totally what's going on there. The :artist/gid is a id attribute defined in the schema for musicbrainz it seems, and the third item looks like the the specific id. I'm not sure what #uuid is.

But, in my case, I have defined no id attribute for my entities. I was hoping to be able to use the unique entity id that I think is assigned by default to each entity. Is this possible? If so, how would this be done?

Comment: The "pull expression using query" is at the very bottom of your linked file.

Comment: @ClojureMostly I'm trying to understand how to use the `pull` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution here is simple. Just drop in the entity id number directly:

`(d/pull db '[*] 17592186045418)`

The mistake I'd made was to use the eid as a string, i.e. by double-quoting it.

Answer (score 3):

Pulls third argument is a reference to an entity. You can either use one of the IDs that your query returned, or a [lookup ref](http://blog.datomic.com/2014/02/datomic-lookup-refs.html), like in the led-zepplin example, where you refer to an entity using a unique attribute value.

Comment: Can you please give an example of what that would look like to use one of the ids that the query returns? Because I tried that without success... Could just be a syntax mistake. Or do you mean that I would (as @AlanThompson suggested) use the `entity` method?

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a query is to find the EID of something given one or more of it's properties. If you already know the EID, you don't need a query, you just want to retrieve the attr/val pairs for that entity. So use the `entity` function:

```
(let [eid  12345
      result (into {} (d/entity db eid)) ]
  (println result))
```

Note that the result of `(d/entity ...)` is lazy and you need to force it into a clojure map to see all of the items.

Besides [Datomic's own documentation](http://docs.datomic.com/), you can find more examples and unit tests [in the Tupelo Datomic library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo-datomic).  Besides containing many convenience functions, [the James Bond example](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo-datomic/blob/master/test/tst/tupelo_datomic/bond.clj) helps to clarify some of the Datomic concepts.

Comment: This is helpful. The only thing I rant into here is that my entities have nested components, which I guess would also need to be recursively forced into maps... Once I figured out that the eid can be used just as a number, and used the pull method, that was nice because it returned the whole structure as a regular data structure.